# I have a problem were my c code doesn't save the char pointer array

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

Hello  am a new at programming and i have a problem. This code is a university school project and was suposed to let the user to create up to 100 accounts and then login to them giving him/her some optios like search, view etc. But the problem is that when i create the second account (the first one is already created in the code) if i decide to to create a third account the previous one is getiing deleted.Also i am writting this code on dev c++ because my university is asking to (just mentionig). Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct userinfo{
    char surname[100];
    char name[100];
    int age;
    int lamia;
    int patra;
    int bolos;
    int totaltrips;
};

int i=0;
void reg(struct userinfo information[100],char *password[100]);
int login(struct userinfo information[100],char *password[100]);
char *passw(char surname[],char temp7[],char password12[]);
void modi(struct userinfo information[100],int person);
void pass(struct userinfo information[100],int person,char *password[100]);
void view(struct userinfo information[100]);
void search(struct userinfo information[100]);
void sort(struct userinfo information[100]);


int main()
{
    char answer[100];
    struct userinfo information[100];
    char *password[100];
    int person;
    do
    {
        do
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("Please enter register if you do not have an account or login if you already have one: ");
            scanf("%s",answer);
        }while (strcmp(answer,"register")!=0 && strcmp(answer,"login")!=0);
        if (strcmp(answer,"register")==0)
        {
            reg(information,password);
            person=i;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            person=login(information,password);
        }
        do
        {
            do
            {   
                printf("\nChoose one of the follow: \nmodify \tpass  \tview  \tsearch \tsort  \texit \n\n");
                scanf("%s",answer);
                system("cls");
            }while(strcmp(answer,"modify")!=0 && strcmp(answer,"pass")!=0 && strcmp(answer,"view")!=0&& strcmp(answer,"search")!=0&& strcmp(answer,"sort")!=0 &&strcmp(answer,"exit")!=0);
            if(strcmp(answer,"modify")==0)
            {
                modi(information,person);
            }
            else if(strcmp(answer,"pass")==0)
            {
                pass(information,person,password);
            }
            else if(strcmp(answer,"view")==0)
            {
                view(information);
            }
            else if(strcmp(answer,"search")==0)
            {
                search(information);
            }
            else if(strcmp(answer,"sort")==0)
            {
                sort(information);
            }
            else if(strcmp(answer,"exit")==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }while(1!=0);
    }while(1!=0);
    return 0;
}


void reg(struct userinfo information[100],char *password[100])
{
    char temp1[10000];
    char temp7[10000];
    char surname[10000];
    char password12[100];
    int valid;
    int k;
    system("cls");
    while(1!=0)
    {
        valid=0;
        printf("Please enter your surname: ");
        scanf("%s",temp1);
        system("cls");
        for (k=0;k<i;k++)
        {
            if (strcmp(temp1,information[k].surname)==0)
            {
                valid=1;
                printf("This surname already exist\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    strcpy(information[i].surname,temp1);
    system("cls");
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",information[i].name);
    printf("\nNow enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",&information[i].age);
    printf("\nEnter the number of trips to Lamia: ");
    scanf("%d",&information[i].lamia);
    printf("\nEnter the number of trips to Patra: ");
    scanf("%d",&information[i].patra);
    printf("\nEnter the number of trips to Bolos: ");
    scanf("%d",&information[i].bolos);
    information[i].totaltrips=information[i].lamia+information[i].patra+information[i].bolos;
    itoa(information[i].totaltrips,temp7,10); /*Ç åíôïëÞ áõôÞ ìåôóôñÝðåé Ýíáí áêÝñáéï óå string */
    strcpy(surname,information[i].surname);/* Ç strcpy áíôéãñÜöåé ôï åðþíõìï ôïõ ôáîéäéþôç áðü ôïí ðßíáêá óå ìéá íÝá ìåôáâëçôÞ ôçí surname */
    password[i]=passw(surname,temp7,password12);
    system("cls");
    printf("Your username is:  %s\nAnd your password is: %s",information[i].surname,password[i]);
}

char *passw(char surname[],char temp7[],char password12[])
{/* Ç strcpy áíôéãñÜöåé ôï åðþíõìï ôïõ ôáîéäéþôç áðü ôïí ðßíáêá óå ìéá íÝá ìåôáâëçôÞ ôçí surname */
    strcat(surname,temp7);
    strcpy(password12,surname);
    return password12;
}

int login(struct userinfo information[100],char *password[100])
{
    int count=0;
    int exist;
    int j=0;
    char username[1000];
    char password2[1000];
    do
    {
        exist=0;
        printf("username: ");
        scanf("%s",username);
        printf("\npassword: ");
        scanf("%s",password2);
        system("cls");
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(username,information[j].surname)==0)
            {
                exist=1;
                count=j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(exist==1)
        {
            if(strcmp(password2,password[count])==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }while (1!=0);
    return count;
}

void modi(struct userinfo information[100],int person)
{
    int answer;
    
        printf("These are your information:\n1.Surname: %s \t2.Name: %s \t3.Age: %d \n4.Total number of trips to Lamia: %d\n5.Total number of trips to Patra: %d\n6.Total number of trips to Bolos: %d",information[person].surname,information[person].name,information[person].age,information[person].lamia,information[person].patra,information[person].bolos);
    do
    {
        printf("\nSelect the number of the iformation you want to change: ");
        scanf("%d",&answer);
    }while(answer<1||answer>6);
    system("cls");
    if (answer==1)
    {
        char temp[100000];
        printf("Enter your new surname:");
        scanf("%s",temp);
        strcpy(information[person].surname,temp);
    }
    else if(answer==2)
    {
        char temp[1000];
        printf("Enter your new name: ");
        scanf("%s",temp);
        strcpy(information[person].name,temp);
    }
    else if(answer==3)
    {
        int temp;
        printf("Enter your new age: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        information[person].age=temp;
    }
    else if(answer==4)
    {
        int temp;
        printf("Enter your new number of trips to Lamia: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        information[person].lamia=temp;
    }
    else if(answer==5)
    {
        int temp;
        printf("Enter your new number of trips to Patra: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        information[person].patra=temp;
    }
    else if(answer==6)
    {
        int temp;
        printf("Enter your new number of trips to Bolos ");
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        information[person].bolos=temp;
    }
}

void pass(struct userinfo information[100],int person,char *password[100])
{
    int sum=5;
    char letter1;
    char letter2;
    char passw2[100];
    if(information[person].totaltrips>20)
    {
        while(information[person].lamia>0 && sum>0)
        {
            information[person].lamia=information[person].lamia-1;
            sum=sum-1;
        }
        while(information[person].patra>0 && sum>0)
        {
            information[person].patra=information[person].patra-1;
            sum=sum-1;  
        }
        while(information[person].bolos>0 && sum>0)
        {
            information[person].bolos=information[person].bolos-1;
            sum=sum-1;
        }
        strcpy(passw2,password[person]);
        if(passw2[0]!='\0'&&passw2[1]!='\0')
        {
            printf("Enter the first letter to change to your password: ");
            scanf(" %c",&letter1);
            passw2[0]=letter1;
            printf("Enter the second letter to change to your password: ");
            scanf(" %c",&letter2);
            passw2[1]=letter2;
            strcpy(password[person],passw2);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Password is too short");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You do not have enough trips to exchange for password change");
    }
}

void view(struct userinfo information[100])
{
    int j;
    int k;
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("Number %d user information: Surname: %s  Name: %s  Age: %d  Total trips: %d ",j+1,information[j].surname,information[j].name,information[j].age,information[j].totaltrips);
    }
    printf("\nThe total number of users is %d",i);
}

void search(struct userinfo information[100])
{
    int total;
    int j;
    printf("Enter the total number of trips to search for: ");
    scanf("%d",&total);
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(information[j].totaltrips==total)
        {
            printf("Surname: %s   Name: %s   Total number of trips: %d",information[j].surname,information[j].name,information[j].totaltrips);
        }
    }
}

void sort(struct userinfo information[100])
{
    char temp1[10000];
    int temp2;
    int j;
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<i;k++)
    {   
        for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(information[j].totaltrips<information[j-1].totaltrips)
            {
                strcpy(temp1,information[j].surname);
                strcpy(information[j].surname,information[j-1].surname);
                strcpy(information[j-1].surname,temp1);
                strcpy(temp1,information[j].name);
                strcpy(information[j].name,information[j-1].name);
                strcpy(information[j-1].name,temp1);
                temp2=information[j].age;
                information[j].age=information[j-1].age;
                information[j-1].age=temp2;
                temp2=information[j].lamia;
                information[j].lamia=information[j-1].lamia;
                information[j-1].lamia=temp2;
                temp2=information[j].patra;
                information[j].patra=information[j-1].patra;
                information[j-1].patra=temp2;
                temp2=information[j].bolos;
                information[j].bolos=information[j-1].bolos;
                information[j-1].bolos=temp2;
                temp2=information[j].totaltrips;
                information[j].totaltrips=information[j-1].totaltrips;
                information[j-1].totaltrips=temp2;
            }
        }
    }
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("Surname: %s   Name: %s   Total trips: %d",information[j].surname,information[j].name,information[j].totaltrips);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! May I suggest you read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) For the code, start with the first of the large number of compiler warnings, and work your way through them until they are all fixed. If you don't understand one, reduce the code to just a few lines, and post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows just that problem.

Comment: Which part is not working correctly in your code ?

Comment: Yeah you're right sorry about my big messy code. Well the problem is in reg fuction that lets the user to create an account. For some reason user can create only one account and if he try to create another one the previous gets deleted.

Comment: Try compiling you program with a C++ compiler and it will help you with a _lot_ of indrection problems.

Comment: Well i tried to use the c++ compiler and the programm started having errors but when i fixed them the program was still not fuctional. To be more specific there is still problem in reg function and every time a try to create an account the system crash. @BoR and everyone else do you know anything else that could work?

Comment: I ran the above code in my C++ compiler and get a lot of errors. E.g., ```: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope for (k=0;k<i;k++)``` Q: is `i` a global variable? ```error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope x[i]=atoi(information[i][3])+atoi(information[i][4])+atoi(information[i][5]);``` How is `x` declared, where does it come from? In `char *passw(char surname[],char temp7[])` I get serious warning `address of local variable ‘password12’ returned`. Your are returning a pointer to a `char password12[1000];` that does not exist after you exit the function.

Comment: What is `char *passw(char surname[],char temp7[])` supposed to do? There is no readable documention of its intent. Then we can better understand what needs to be done. `reg` is too messy now to correct.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&temp1);` should be `scanf("%s",temp1);` and this goes for the other `scanf` uses on `tempN` variables. In `void reg(char *information[100][7],char *password[100])` are you storing 100 passwords in some array of pointers? If you are adding to it you need to allocate memory for this. The same goes for `information`, you don't seem to be allocating memory for all these pointers to "own" the content they are pointing to.

Comment: So i fixed all there errors i think but the program still doesn't work. Also the code i posted is part of a bigger code so thats why many variables are not declared. I will update the code with the variables declared in 5minutes and with most of the erros fixed. Also @BoR you were right that programm was meant to create up to 100 accounts with username and passwords were the username and the information of the accounts are in one char array and the passwords on another array.

Comment: The magic number `7` in the code does really convey what it is. Consider replacing the numbers with constants (or macros if you have to) to convey there meaning. The program will be eaiser to read *and* modify.

Comment: So i udated the code. Thank you for your advice and sorry for the trouble but i am working for some days in this code and i have no idea what is happeing.

Comment: `strncpy` can create an array without terminating 0 byte. You must take care about that manually

Comment: And how i will do this ?

Comment: You need to look into `malloc/free` if you need dynamic content. BTW, does this assigment *have* to be in C och can you use C++?

Comment: Ok I will take a look at malloc/free and yeah the assignment is necesaary to be in C.

Comment: With fixed lengh buffers for strings in your structure the whole thing becomes easier. See my proposed answer. But the `passw` is still not doing what you belive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify the information you need to handle in some steps.

Define a structure for the information you handle. Currently you are
using char-strings for almost everything. Here is a proposed structure:

```c
#define SURNAME_MAXLEN 50
#define NAME_MAXLEN 30

struct UserInfo {
   char surname[SURNAME_MAXLEN + 1];  // aka username
   char name[NAME_MAXLEN + 1];
   int age;
   int nrLamiaTrips;
   int nrPatraTrips;
   int nrBolosTrips;
   int totalNrTrips;  // the sum of nrLamiaTrips, nrPatraTrips, and nrBolosTrips
};
```

The beginning of `main` will start to look simpler (and notice the `= {0};` to initialize the arrays to zeros):

```c
int main()
{
   struct UserInfo information[100] = {0}; /* Here are .... */
   char *password[100] = {0}; /* Here are ... */
   int i=0;
   int x[100]; /* Here is ... */ // With the change in `information`
                                 // x might not be needed anymore.
   char tempSurname[SURNAME_MAXLEN+1]; // used to be called `temp1`
```

with then new name of `temp1` code can be written:

```c
      printf("Please enter your surname: ");
      scanf("%50s",tempSurname);
```

Since we know what it is we are reading and have defined limits on how long it is, we can code that into the `scanf` string. So, in this examaple, we don't accept usernames of more than 50 characters.

Searching now looks more like this instead of magic numbers `[k][0]`:

```c
      for (k=0;k<i;k++)
      {
         if (strcmp(tempSurname,information[k].surname)==0)
```

and storing can now be improved with

```c
   strcpy(information[i].surname, tempSurname); // since we know to source is not too long
```

Other information can be read without a temporary for strings

```c
   printf("Please enter your name: ");
   scanf("%30s",information[i].name);
```

or for integers

```c
   printf("\nNow enter your age: ");
   scanf("%d", &information[i].age);
```

Adding things becomes eaiser to read

```
   x[i] = information[i].nrLamiaTrips + information[i].nrPatraTrips+ information[i].nrBolosTrips;
   information[i].totalNrTrips = x[i];
```

(Do we really need `x` still?)

Comment: Thanks a lot I will sure check it but do you have any idea why my code wasn't working?

Comment: When I ran it this `strncpy(information[i][0],temp1,sizeof information[i][0]-1);`  was the first line that crashed. The reason being that there is no memory storage location that the content of `temp1` can go. `information[i][0]` is just a wild pointer (uninitialized) and not a location of where you want to write the results. Also, depending on architecture used (32/64-bit),  `sizeof information[i][0]-1` is just another way of writing  `7` (64-bit)  or `3` (32-bit) and not what you are expecting. `sizeof(char*) - 1` is what you are getting since the dest is not  an array but a pointer.

Comment: Hello again. Sorry @Bor to bother you again. The code is working way better now but it still doesn't save the information of the accounts. I updated again the code above to check it if you want to.

Comment: @Peter, you are still not storing your passwords properly. You just have an array of pointers *to* to password for each user. Why not add the passwords to the `userinfo` as a field just like `surname` and `name`?  The line `password[i]=passw(surname,temp7,password12);` gets you in trouble since it stores a pointer to a local variable `password12` that then goes out of scope. That's the trouble with the password handling.

Comment: Yeah you were right now my programm works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.